# Laravel :Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated(), 2 passed

Tags: laravel, frameworks

I am getting this error On `GeoIP::getLocation` when I send data to MySQL Database

This Error:

> "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated(), 2 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\codecrowne\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php on line 108 and exactly 3 expected"

I am getting above error on this code on auth logincontroller .

This Is My Auth LoginController.php On User Login i am updating user data into database. All the data store into database but when i add this code `'current_location' => GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31'),` i am getting this error

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Closure;
use GeoIP;
use Location;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    function authenticated(Request $request, $user, Closure $next)
  {
    // Chrome, IE, Safari, Firefox, ...
          $agent = new Agent();
        $browser = $agent->browser();
        // Ubuntu, Windows, OS X, ...
         $platform = $agent->platform();


    $user->update([
        'last_signin' => Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString(),
        'ip_address' => $request->getClientIp(),
        'browser_login' => $agent->browser(),
        'browser_version' => $agent->version($browser),
        'device_login' => $agent->platform(),
        'device_version' => $agent->version($platform),
         'current_location' => GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31'),
        'language' =>  $agent->languages(),
        'root' => $agent->robot(),
        'https' => $request->server('HTTP_USER_AGENT'),
    ]);
  }
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */



    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest',['except'=>['logout', 'userLogout', 'profile']]);
    }
     public function userLogout()
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Route File:

```
 //User Auth Route Function 
  Auth::routes();
```

Comment: Can you show where you're calling the `authenticated()` method from?

Comment: All data store into database but when i add this code GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31') i am getting error

Comment: Please can you edit your question and add your routes file and the rest of your controller? Also are you saying that if you remove `'current_location' => GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31'),` you no longer get the error?

Comment: Please Check I have added every code, please let me know your answer

Comment: Yeah If i remove this 'current_location' => GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31'), i am not getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AuthenticatesUsers` trait you are including into this class contains an `authenticated` method which you are overriding with a different method signature containing an additional parameter.

This method signature only expects 2 arguments, as you can see:

```
protected mixed authenticated(Request $request, mixed $user)
```

However, in your controller, you have a third parameter `Closure $next`. The error message is correctly advising you that the method is expecting 3 parameters, however, it's only being provided with 2.

If you remove the third parameter (you're not using it anyway), your code should work.

Comment: after removing `Closure $next` i am getting this error `Object of class Torann\GeoIP\Location could not be converted to string`

Comment: @SagarAmbade this is a different problem now. I guess your line of code `GeoIP::getLocation('2405:204:970a:d9b3:10a3:5280:9064:3f31')` is returning an `Object` which you are trying to store as a string in the database.